# How to solve problem building images with Podman: "sd-bus call: Connection reset by peer"?

Tags: docker, d-bus, podman

Building a PostgreSQL image with podman 3.1.2 (previous 3.0.1) results in

> sd-bus call: Connection reset by peer

This also happens when executing example from Podman http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/Introduction.html

```
podman build -t nginx https://git.io/Jf8ol
```

Below example should build a PostgreSQL server.

I have installed package podman on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (running on Raspi 4) with

```
apt install podman
podman -v
-> podman version 3.0.1
```

Trying to build PostgreSQL results in:

```
 podman build -t djarjo/postgresql -f postgresql_deDE .

STEP 1: FROM postgres:13.3
STEP 2: RUN localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.UTF-8
error running container: error creating container for [/bin/sh -c localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.UTF-8]: sd-bus call: Connection reset by peer
: exit status 1
Error: error building at STEP "RUN localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.UTF-8": error while running runtime: exit status 1
```

The build file is:

```
cat postgresql_deDE
FROM postgres:13.3
RUN localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias   de_DE.UTF-8
ENV LANG de_DE.utf8
```